# Функция getSelection не работает iOS 12

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

Функции document.getSelection() и window.getSelection() не работают в iOS 12.

Проблема воспроизводится в Safari, Google Chrome и WKWebView.

В iOS 11 и MacOS (любая версия) эти функции работают.

Нужны любые идеи, как получить выделение текста пользователем.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/50zej8pb/2/)

```
document.querySelector("#contentjs").onclick = function () {
    console.log(document.getSelection());
    document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = document.getSelection().anchorOffset;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение проблемы - использование функции
document.caretRangeFromPoint

Пример:

```
document.querySelector("#contentjs").onclick = function (e) {
    var range = document.caretRangeFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    console.log(range.startOffset);
    console.log(range.startContainer);
}
```